# Universal App Uses Wrong Xib for iPad in iOS 6 Simulator

Tags: ipad, ios6, ios-simulator, plist, xib

In the Simulator, my universal app runs fine in iOS 5, but in iOS 6 it grabs MainWindow.xib instead of MainWindow~ipad.xib.  I have "Main Nib File Base Name (iPad)" (NSMainNibFile~ipad) set properly in the plist.  Every other combination works fine (iPhone, iPhone HD, iPhone 5, and iPad on iOS 5; iPhone, iPhone HD, and iPhone 5 on iOS 6).

Here's the relevant section from the plist:

```
<key>NSMainNibFile</key>
<string>MainWindow</string>
<key>NSMainNibFile~ipad</key>
<string>MainWindow~ipad</string>
```

I'm at my wit's end, having recreated the iPad Xib from scratch, reset the Simulator, cleaned Xcode's cache (Clean menu option and DerivedData folder), and everything else I could think of short of sacrificing a chicken (including the ideas on [Universal app for iPad not loading iPad .xib files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9753967/universal-app-for-ipad-not-loading-ipad-xib-files)).  I'm running the current version of Xcode (4.5.2) on Lion.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solution: use "MainWindow~iPhone.xib" (iPhone) and "MainWindow.xib" (iPad).

The answer was found in this old post:

http://oleb.net/blog/2010/04/universal-app-is-not-a-universal-binary/

but was also in the linked thread above (I had some other problems, including some missing Xib connections, which may have caused it to fail for me earlier).

Comment: Sorry, false alarm.  All that did was make the iPad version work and the iPhone version fail.

Comment: The real solution: "You can explicitly[...] specify the nib file. Go to Xib/MainWindow-iPhone.xib/Base ViewC, under the Attributes tab on the right, you should see a View Controller section. Under the NIB Name, select BaseViewC-iPhone. Do the same for the rest of Xib file."